# Замена двух обратных слешей на один

Tags: python

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как бороться с двойными обратными слешами? Есть строка, например`'a\\b'`, как из неё сделать `'a\b'` и сохранить результат в переменную? Работаю на винде. У меня скрипт передает внешней программе путь к файлу в качестве параметра (через subprocess). По-любому нужно двойные обратные слеши заменить на один обратный еще до запуска той программы, потому что она их не понимает.

`replace('\\\\','\\')`

и другие манипуляции с неформатированными строками толку не дают. При выводе на экран с помощью print() показывает как надо, но в переменную сохранить с одинарными слешами не получается. Как быть?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте функцию `os.path.normpath`

Comment: Спасибо, но это тоже не дает требуемый результат.
Решение нашлось опытным путем: если программе передавать путь к файлу без ключа r'a\\b', то двойной слеш становится одним. Для проверки сделал скрипт на питоне:

from subprocess import call\n
call('C:\test.exe '+'a\\\\b')

Test.exe - это скомпилированный скрипт AutoIt3. Его содержание:

MsgBox(0,"Test backslash", $CmdLine[1])

В сообщении написан один слеш

a\b

А если нужно два оставить, то перед строкой просто приписываешь r и все работает как надо. Значит проблемы и не было.
Всем спасибо.

Comment: Как видите >>>len('a\\b') дает результат 3, а не 4